# Pandas: Pythonic way to create new df by summing columns from different dfs

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have two dfs

df1

```
  a b
z 3 4
x 1 3
```

and

df2

```
  a b 
c 4 8
v 6 1
```

I want to create df3 which has two new rows [b,n] and its values are based on summing the columns [a,b] from my two dfs like this :

df3

```
  a  b
b 4  7
n 10 9
```

I know this can be done simply by using .sum() on both dataframes and simply creating df3 manually, like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[4,7],[10,9]], columns = ['a','b'])
```

I just wanted to know if there is a more pythonic way of doing this that uses a single function or iteration to generate it in less time.

Comment: I edit answer, I think you want `pd.concat([df1[['a','b']], df2[['a','b']]], keys=['b', 'n']).sum(level=0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) by first level:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['b', 'n']).sum(level=0)
print (df3)
    a  b
b   4  7
n  10  9
```

Solution for multiple `DataFrames`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...]
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=range(len(dfs))).sum(level=0)
```

EDIT:

If want sum only some columns:

```
 cols = set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns)
df3 = pd.concat([df1[['a','b']], df2[['a','b']]], keys=['b', 'n']).sum(level=0)
```

And for all columns in both DataFrames:

```
cols = list(set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns))
df3 = pd.concat([df1[cols], df2[cols]], keys=['b', 'n']).sum(level=0)
print (df3)
    a  b
b   4  7
n  10  9
```

Comment: You sir, just won a cookie. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `sum` and `concat`.

```
pd.concat([df1.sum(), df2.sum()], 1).T

    a  b
0   4  7
1  10  9
```

Or, with a `keys` argument -

```
pd.concat([df1.sum(), df2.sum()], 1, keys=['b', 'n']).T
    a  b
b   4  7
n  10  9
```

If you have many such dataframes, and assuming they have the same columns, you can put them into a single list and call sum inside a list comprehension -

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]
pd.concat([df.sum() for df in df_list], 1, keys=['b', 'n']).T

    a  b
b   4  7
n  10  9
```

Comment: First of all thank you for this great great line of code.

We are very close but not there!

df3.ab is basically the sum of df1.a / df3bb is the sum of df1.b

Same for df3.an is the sum of df2.a / df3.bn being the sum of df2.b

So when I do:
df3 = pd.concat([[df1.a.sum(), df1.b.sum()], [df2.a.sum(), df2.b.sum()]], 1, keys=['b', 'n']).T

I get: 
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

I would also like to mention that the number of rows I have in each df are more than two and are not the same in number in df1 and df2.

Thank you again for all your time!